# Does wait work without SIGCHLD?

Tags: signals, wait

I have a parent process that runs a child process and then wait for it:

```
myprocess &
wait $!
```

However, when `myprocess` exits, the parent process continues waiting for it. After listing the signals with:

```
kill -l
```

There is not `SIGCHLD` in my distribution.

Does `wait` work without `SIGCHLD`?

Thank you

Comment: Your distribution? Your _Linux_ distribution?  All Linux distros have `SIGCHLD`.

Comment: Does `kill -l` list `SIGCLD`? Some ancient unices had SIGCLD rather than SIGCHLD (with similar but not identical semantics). The `wait` command doesn't necessarily require SIGC(H)LD, but it's a common way to implement it. What unix variant is this? What shell is this?

Comment: There is no need to wait explicitly for `$!`, which is the pid of the last process started in background. A plain `wait` (in `bash and ksh` at least) waits for all background processes. And shell necessarily uses SIGCHLD, because it has to still monitor terminal input concurrently, and it has to support the shell `trap` command. Get more output like: `myscript & jobs; sleep 5; jobs; wait; jobs;` and post it.

Comment: @AndyDalton It is a custom Linux distribution created using Yocto.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Thank you for your comment. In fact the SIGCHLD is listed as CHLD and I didn't notice it yesterday. Would you post your comment as an answer, so I could accept it as the answer to my problem?

Comment: @Paul_Pedant In this scenario, I only want to wait for the last child process. Thank you for the suggestions on how to get more output.

Comment: We don't have enough info to help. You could `echo $!` and see what it is. You could run `jobs` and see if the process is listed there. You could run `ps -ef | awk '$2 == '"$!"` and see if the process is running. You could `kill -CHLD 77777` and see if kill says "invalid signal specification" or "No such process". You could run `uname -a`. You could check that your script does not have CR/LF terminations.

Comment: I tried to recreate this issue for a couple of hours today, with various timing conditions, and failed to break anything on bash version 4.3.48(1) on x86_64 and Linux Mint. So, notes: (1) I would recommend saving Pids immediately like `myprocess & PID_3="${!}"`, and using `wait "${PID_3}"` -- that is, don't rely on `$!` being stable; (2) I have a `Wait()` bash function that checks in a timed loop for a pid no longer being running in the jobs list, which may work around your issue; (3) I can PasteBin my whole test pack if you want to investigate further on your own system.

Comment: Addendum: my Wait() function does not collect status, so the child process becomes a zombie. This does no harm -- it will be culled later by your shell or the system. All Wait() does is to block your shell until the specified child either disappears from the jobs list, or is listed with status "Done".

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Thank you for further investigating the problem. I still could not reproduce the problem with test programs. My work around was to rewrite the script to not rely on wait as you suggested.